# ARM Resource Not Found when trying to use Outputs, have tried a lot

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM Template that is nested (one file). In the parent-scope, there are just 2 resources that get deployed:

1. A resource group, with a name that is dictated by a parameter name.
2. A deployment resource, which is the sub-template. The resource group is listed in the dependsOn property.

In the sub-template, I am deploying a bunch of Vaults and Secrets. I'm trying to get, in the outputs, some attributes of the secret and the vault (vault name, secret URI, etc).
I've tried a bunch of different syntax, and they all yield errors for me. Not sure what else I can try, so I decided to come here for some advice.

Trying to get data from vaults (in this case name, but just testing):

```
"vaultName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults','TestVault123123'), '2017-05-10', 'Full').name]"
                    }
```

error: The Resource 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/TestVault123124' under resource group null was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix

```
                            "value": "[reference(resourceId('redacted-for-stackoverflow', parameters('rgName'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults','TestVault123124'), '2017-05-10', 'Full').name]"
```

error: 2021-05-10T18:41:03.6121120Z ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template output 'resourceGroupName2' at line '1' and column '26299' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires fully qualified resource type 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults' as one of first three arguments for resource at resource group scope, or first two arguments for resource at subscription scope. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.

Trying to get output (URI) from a Secret (TestVault123123 is in the same "deployment" resource as the secret:

```
"mySecretUri": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', 'TestVault123123', 'TestSecret123123'), '2017-05-10').secretUri]"
                    },
```

error: "error": {
"code": "ParentResourceNotFound",
"message": "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'TestVault123123' not found."
}
}

EDIT: Full Template
Note: ID's have been replaced with "redacted-guid".

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "rgName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "sample"
    },
    "vaultName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "TestVault333555"
    }
},
"variables": {

},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
        "location": "West US",
        "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
        "properties": {}
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
        "name": "keyVaultsDeployment",
        "resourceGroup": "[parameters('rgName')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('rgName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "parameters": {},
                "variables": {},
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
                        "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
                        "name": "[parameters('vaultName')]",
                        "location": "westus",
                        "tags": {
                            "Environment": "Development",
                            "ResourceType": "Vaults"
                        },
                        "properties": {
                            "sku": {
                                "family": "A",
                                "name": "Standard"
                            },
                            "tenantId": "redacted-guid",
                            "accessPolicies": [
                                {
                                    "tenantId": "redacted-guid",
                                    "objectId": "redacted-guid",
                                    "permissions": {
                                        "keys": [
                                            "Get"
                                        ],
                                        "secrets": [
                                            "Get"
                                        ],
                                        "certificates": []
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "tenantId": "redacted-guid",
                                    "objectId": "redacted-guid",
                                    "permissions": {
                                        "keys": [
                                            "Get",
                                            "List",
                                            "Update",
                                            "Create",
                                            "Import",
                                            "Delete",
                                            "Recover",
                                            "Backup",
                                            "Restore"
                                        ],
                                        "secrets": [
                                            "Get",
                                            "List",
                                            "Set",
                                            "Delete",
                                            "Recover",
                                            "Backup",
                                            "Restore"
                                        ],
                                        "certificates": [
                                            "Get",
                                            "List",
                                            "Update",
                                            "Create",
                                            "Import",
                                            "Delete",
                                            "Recover",
                                            "Backup",
                                            "Restore",
                                            "ManageContacts",
                                            "ManageIssuers",
                                            "GetIssuers",
                                            "ListIssuers",
                                            "SetIssuers",
                                            "DeleteIssuers"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "enabledForDeployment": false,
                            "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
                            "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false,
                            "enableSoftDelete": true,
                            "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 90,
                            "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
                            "enablePurgeProtection": true,
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
                        "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/SECRET')]",
                        "location": "westus",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName'))]"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "enabled": true
                            },
                            "value": "redacted-guid"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": {
                    "secret": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', parameters('vaultName'), 'SECRET'), '2017-05-10', 'Full').secretUri]"
                    },
                    "vaultLocation": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName')), '2017-05-10', 'Full').location]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {

}
}

Errors:
2021-05-11T20:54:39.6696772Z ##[error]NotFound: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/TestVault333555' under resource group '<null>' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"
  }
}
2021-05-11T20:54:39.6698437Z ##[error]NotFound: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ParentResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'TestVault333555' not found."
  }
}
```

On Azure, in the release pipeline, in the ARM Template Deployment Job, the deployment scope is set to "Subscription". It's my understanding that this is necessary because I wanted to create a brand new resource group and deploy the resources underneath that. If the deployment scope is set to "Resource Group" it requires me to specify the RG in the pipeline, which I don't want, because I want to create it at execution.

Comment: Can you please upload the ARM Template so that I can give it a try.

Comment: Created a sample template that emulates the same issue and posted above @JagratiModi . Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

i've done some testing w/ the Powershell SDK and the Template you provided and managed to get rid of the 'resource group null was not found'-error.

So a couple of things- because this is not a resource group deployment you need to change the $schema (for example subscription scope):

```
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
```

to

```
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
```

For more information on deployment scopes and ARM-templates, see [Scopes Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax#template-format)

Second, in your deployment resource you haven't set the 'expressionEvaluationOptions'-property which means you cannot use the reference function in the output section. You have to declare them in the 'original' template OR set the 'expressionEvaluationOptions'-property to 'inner'. See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#expression-evaluation-scope-in-nested-templates) for your problem.

I also noticed the 'provisioningState'-property so you pasted the template from an earlier deployment of the portal. That doesn't always work and most of your 'apiVersions'-properties are outdated

so TLDR:

- use $schema that fits your scenario
- declare Outputs in parent template OR set 'expressionEvaluationOptions'-property to 'inner'
- Update all 'apiVersion'-properties